# NA Remove to calculation

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have some problems with NA value cause my dataset from excel is not same column number so It showed NA. It deleted all row containing NA value when make calculation Similarity Index function Psicalc in RInSp package.

```
B   F
4   7
5   6
6   8
7   5
NA  4
NA  3
NA  2
```

Do you know how to handle with NA or remove it but not delete all row or not affect to package?. Beside when I import.RinSP it has message 
In if (class(filename) == "character") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Thank you so much

Comment: Please show which function you called, show the actual code. Some functions (e.g. `sum(), mean()` etc) have NA-friendly switches, others don't.

Comment: For the latter (functions without `na.rm=`), you may be able to use `na.omit(x)` inside of your other function; there are of course stipulations about this depending on your calculations, your assumptions, and how robust you want to be to the missingness of data. (For instance, some functions do very poorly when there are zero non-`NA` observations.)

Comment: @smci I wanna do RInSp package to calculate Similarity Index (Psicalc).

Comment: Hey @PhanCôngthẮng, i looked at the package.. So if there is NA you cannot calculate pairwise distance. If the NA indicates zero, like zero detetcion (you have to know this!!!) , then if your data frame is df, df[!is.na(df)] = 0

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, thank you so much. NA in my dataset means blank cells. Column B just have 4 rows so that's why NA appear.

Comment: Phan Công thẮng, that suggests to me that your "table" does not need to be a single `data.frame`. Typically, rows in a `data.frame` represent observations, and each column is an attribute of that observation. Every observation has all attributes (though some can obviously be `NA`). In this case, when you say *"Column B just have 4 rows"*, that suggests that its rows do not mean the same as the rows in the next column ("F") ... so storing them in a `data.frame` is not really necessary or even appropriate. (Perhaps a `list`, named or otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

Many R functions ( specifically base R ) have an `na.rm` argument, which is FALSE by default. That means if you omit this argument, and your data has NA, your "calculation" will result in NA. To remove these in the calculations,  include an `na.rm` argument and assign it to TRUE.

Example:

```
x <- c(4,5,6,7,NA,NA)
mean(x)  # Oops!
[1] NA

mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 5.5
```